# Не работает поиск по названию в массиве структур (C++)

Tags: c++

Не работает поиск по названию (case 2) в массиве структур, всё время пишет "Ошибка, такого значения нет!", но поиск по номеру и размеру клетки работает. Помогите пожалуйста!

```
void searchdata(zoo *M, int N) { // поиск элемента массива структур
    int select, find1;
    char find2[20];
    float find3;
    bool tmp = false;
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "<< Поиск элемента массива структур >>" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Введите номер поля, по которому будет выполняться поиск (1 - номер, 2 - название, 3 - размер клетки): ";
    cin >> select;
    switch (select)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Введите номер, который нужно найти: ";
        cin >> find1;
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (M[i].number == find1) {
                cout << "<< Найдено >>" << endl;
                cout << "Номер: ";
                cout << M[i].number << endl;
                cout << "Название: ";
                cout << M[i].name << endl;
                cout << "Размер клетки: ";
                cout << M[i].size << endl << endl;
                tmp = true;
            }
        }
        if (tmp != true)
        {
            cout << "<< Ошибка >>" << endl;
            cout << "Такого значения нет!" << endl << endl;
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "Введите название, которое нужно найти: ";
        cin >> find2;
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (M[i].name == find2)
            {
                cout << "<< Найдено >>" << endl;
                cout << "Номер: ";
                cout << M[i].number << endl;
                cout << "Название: ";
                cout << M[i].name << endl;
                cout << "Размер клетки: ";
                cout << M[i].size << endl << endl;
                tmp = true;
            }
        }
        if (tmp != true)
        {
            cout << "<< Ошибка >>" << endl;
            cout << "Такого значения нет!" << endl << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Введите значение поля, которое нужно найти: ";
        cin >> find3;
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (M[i].size == find3)
            {
                cout << "<< Найдено >>" << endl;
                cout << "Номер: ";
                cout << M[i].number << endl;
                cout << "Название: ";
                cout << M[i].name << endl;
                cout << "Размер клетки: ";
                cout << M[i].size << endl << endl;
                tmp = true;
            }
        }
        if (tmp != true)
        {
            cout << "<< Ошибка >>" << endl;
            cout << "Такого значения нет!" << endl << endl;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете сравнивать два массива на char через ==, по сути в сравниваете адреса двух разных массивов. Чтобы сравнить сами строки нужно использовать [std::strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) или [std::strncmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncmp) из заголовочного файла [cstring](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring), причём значение, возвращаемое этими функциями будет отрицательным - если левая строка лексикографически **меньше** второй, равно 0 - если **равны**, больше 0 - если левая строка лексикографически **больше** второй:

```
const int strMax = 20;
char strA[strMax] = "...";
char strB[strMax] = "...";
if (std::strcmp(strA, strB) == 0) { // или (std::strncmp(strA, strB, strMax) == 0)
    // строки одинаковые
} else {
    // строки разные
}
```

или использовать [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
std::string a = someString();
std::string b = someString();
if (a == b) {
    // строки одинаковые
} else {
    // строки разные
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можете написать под мой код, если Вам не сложно?

Comment: @slvk.m `if (strcmp(M[i].name, find2) == 0)`

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает